# My app crashes on startup when i deploy it on my android device

Tags: android

I am following the developer.android.com training and I've just learned how to add text and a button and I don't think I've changed anything and done the exact same thing asked. I get no errors, but when I deploy it on my phone it crashes saying

> unfortunately MyFirstApp has stopped working

. Please check my code and see if there are any mistakes.Also, ive tried cleaning and rebuilding, it still crashes.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.MyFirstApp.yoo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return true;
 }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
     // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is my activity_main.xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.MyFirstApp.yoo.MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" >
</EditText>

<button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my strings.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">My First App</string>
<string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
<string name="button_send">Send</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings </string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

</resources>
```

And this is my MyFirstApp Manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.MyFirstApp.yoo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The logcat

```
      07-24 19:05:54.175: W/dalvikvm(32427): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1864  (ActionBarWindow) in Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
07-24 19:05:54.175: D/dalvikvm(32427): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0004
07-24 19:05:54.175: D/AndroidRuntime(32427): Shutting down VM
07-24 19:05:54.175: W/dalvikvm(32427): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416502a0)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:106)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at com.MyFirstApp.yoo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
07-24 19:05:54.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32427):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: **ALWAYS** include the logcat in your question of you get exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide error log.. 
Also try to use,

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"/>
```

instead of

```
<button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"/>
```

Comment: WOW THAT WORKED! Can you please explain how changing it to a capital B can make such a big difference? is it a syntax?

Comment: If worked then please accept this answer :) .. Yeas you can consider it as syntax.

Comment: ohh, but did you understand this by reading the logcat? if so how?
And yes ill accept it now, thank you SO much!